# How can i write in a Java File?

Tags: java

I want to write in a File but i am having a very extrange problem.
If i write the code like this:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nom + ".txt"));
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSIO; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSIO; j++) {
                s +=tauler.isBomba(i,j);
                s += '\n';
                s +=tauler.isSeleccionat(i,j);
                s += '\n';
            }
        }
        bw.write(s);
```

The file is empty, but if I write the code in this way:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(nom + ".txt"));
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSIO; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSIO; j++) {
                s +=tauler.isBomba(i,j);
                s += '\n';
                s +=tauler.isSeleccionat(i,j);
                s += '\n';
                bw.write(s);
            }
        }
```

It works. The problem is that in the second way it's not correct cause i need to write it after the for.

Comment: How are you checking what has been written? A *Buffered*Writer buffers the output, so you might need to flush it. Also the second way is writing a lot more text.

Answer (score 4):

You need to close the `BufferedWriter` object at the end.

```
bw.close();
```

That causes the data to get flushed out of the stream to the file. I think the reason it works when it's inside the loop is that it is flushing the data periodically.

But a better way to write this, as suggested by Clashsoft, is to use a `try-with-resource` statement instead, which will handle closing the `BufferedWriter` automatically.

```
try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName))) {
    // do your logic here
    writer.write(str);

    // once control leaves this block, the writer gets closed automatically
}
catch(IOException e){
    // handle the exception
}
```

Comment: OMG. It worked i am such a fool. I spent like three days.
Thanks!

Comment: @Clashsoft - Good point, I've edited the answer to reflect your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `bw.close()` after you call `bw.write(s);`